# Каким способом можно динамически выводить графику, созданную в C#?

Tags: c#, .net, 3d

С целью обучения и саморазвития хочу создать 3D пространство, сцену и рендер. Принципиально не хочу "списывать" с уже готовых графических 3D движков, и тем более - использовать их. Интересует изучение математики и геометрии, поэтому все, что требуется от визуализации - динамическое обновление отображаемых данных (не менее нескольких кадров в секунду) и простота. Не хочу сейчас тратить время на изучение direcx и подобных тяжелых систем отображения.
В данный момент на ум приходит только использование фигур в объекте canvas в html. Но это означает, что придется использовать javascript и налаживать транспорт данных между языками. Может есть способ еще проще?

Comment: MonoGame (в прошлом Microsoft XNA)? По сути, является ооп-оберткой над DirectX/SDL2.

Comment: Как бы так ничего не учить и ничего не делать, но чтобы все работало?